# How to set x-www-form-urlencoded parameters in WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an API Which Takes `x-www-form-urlencoded` Values in Parameters. Its Working Fine in Postman but I don't Know How to Set It in WSO2.

Here is My API in Postman. In Body Section I Send Data with `Content/Type: x-www-form-urlencoded` .This Encodes the values of keys. but I did not see such thing in WSO2.

[image]
How can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you deployed the API in API Manager? The question is not clear. Can you add more details

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added a screenshot.

Comment: What do you mean by "Set in APIM?" You want to hardcode these values in a custom sequence?

Comment: What is your OAS version of the REST API you created in API Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the deployed API is based on OAS 3.x, you can edit the API Definition by following the steps given below:

1. Login to the Publisher Portal (by browsing `https://<host>:<port>/publisher`)
2. Select the particular API
3. Navigate to the `API Definitions` section
4. Edit the relevant resource as mentioned below:

```yaml
  /getorder:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                orderid:
                  type: string
                passengerid:
                  type: string
                ordercode:
                  type: string
```

5. Save the changes
6. Now if you try to invoke the API from DevPortal, it will prompt for the fields as shown below:

[image]